# Key-based SSH login with Nautilus' "Connect to Server"

Tags: nautilus, ssh

I tried loggin into an SSH server via Nautilus' "Connect to Server" feature by just leaving the password blank, but that didn't work.

How do I connect to my server using the key I have on my system?

Comment: For ubuntu 14.04, see this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/630323/139574)

Comment: For ubuntu 18.04 see this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/953134/300767)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of entering the username in the fields below, you'll have to prepend `user@` to the server address and leave both username and password blank:

[image]

Comment: I just tried this but receive 'Permission denied'. I can ssh in via the terminal, but only after I `cd` to the directory containing the key. Do I need to move the key somewhere else, or tell Nautilus where to find it somehow?

Comment: Figured it out, finally. If the above answer doesn't work for you (seems to be a common problem for EC2 users) try `ssh-add path/to/keyfile` and try again. That fixed it instantly for me.

Answer (score 17):

I needed to connect to EC2 instance using .pem key + connect using normal username-password mode. I solved these requirements by including the Host aliases in `~/.ssh/config` file. **Example:**

```
Host ssh_using_key
HostName abc.myawesomesite.com
User ubuntu
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/MyPrivateKey.pem
Compression yes

Host ssh_using_userpass
HostName 173.193.72.103
User root
Port 2222
```

Now as described above, go to File > Connect to Server in Nautilus. **Example:**

**For SSH using Key:**

```
Server = ssh_using_key (as in the ~/.ssh/config file)
Type = SSH
Folder = /var/www
[leave User Details BLANK.]
```

**For SSH using Username and Password:**

```
Server = ssh_using_userpass (as in the ~/.ssh/config file)
Port = 2222
Type = SSH
Folder = /home/www
User name = root
Password = lamepassword
Check Remember this password.
```

Please modify this according to your need. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I had no idea you could use ssh hosts with Nautilus, just entering `sftp://my-ec2` and having Nautilus just work is amazing. Combine that with Right Click -> "Open in Remote Terminal", and Nautilus is actually a pretty decent FTP/SSH client.

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned [by Tom Brossman in one a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102608/key-based-ssh-login-with-nautilus-connect-to-server/102609#comment444324_102609), try this:

```
ssh-add path
```

where `path` is the path of your `.pem` file.

Comment: yeah, this did work flawlessly!

Comment: The best answer. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when I stopped using Unity and switched to Gnome3 as my machine crawled along despite being way above spec with Unity.

Anyway, I first removed my ~/.ssh/known_hosts file to ensure it wasn't a fingerprint issue. It was not so I don't think this step was necessary.

I then tried (just for the hell of it as I'd tried everything else by now) **entering my passPHRASE where it asked for my password**. Lo and behold it worked.

Comment: Did you leave the user name field blank?

Answer (score 2):

**For Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

The nautilus window has slightly changed.

**Pre-requisites:**

1. Log in to the server.
2. Add your public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Open nautilus on your local computer.

Log in using this URL format: `ssh://user@server`. To cd to anything other than your home patch, append with a slash. `ssh://user@server/var/www` for example.

Answer (score 2):

I tried [Sagun's approach](https://askubuntu.com/a/386286/22949), but the UI for connecting to server is different in 16.04. The command or argument required now is `ssh://ssh_using_key`.

Answer (score 2):

**For those who are using key.pem follow this its works for me:**

change your key.pem file permission using:

```
sudo chmod 700 key.pem
```

and then add this to ~/.ssh/config (this file may not exist, if so then create it using 'cd ~/.ssh/' and then 'sudo nano config'):

```
Host my_server
HostName 111.0.0.1
User ubuntu
IdentityFile /home/user/somefolder/key.pem
```

111.0.0.1 is your server ip address, you can find it using this command:

```
ping mysite.com
```

and then try with Nautilus/File 'Connect to Server':

```
sftp://ubuntu@myserver/home
sftp://ubuntu@myserver/var/www
sftp://ubuntu@myserver/etc
```

You can change directory like this when you connect.

**OR Alternatively** easy way you can use 'Remmina Remote Desktop Client' built-in on Ubuntu, you can find it on Dashboard

Thanks.