# How can connect server using .ppk key file

Tags: software-recommendation

I am new in linux.
I am using `winscp` and `PuTTY` Pageant File (.ppk) file to connect server in WINDOWS

My questions are

1. What is a program similar to WinSCP?
2. How can I use my current .ppk file in linux?

Sorry for my poor English.
Thanks jobish.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use PuTTY in Ubuntu as well

```
sudo apt-get install putty
```

The equivalent to Putty in Linux, however, is to use ssh on the command line

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/key user@server
```

You will need to convert your putty key (using PuTTYgen) to an openssh key or make a new key.

To convert the key, first import it, then export it as an openssh key.

[image: convert key]

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/ConnectingTo

You can use any number of programs to connect similar to WinSCP, nautilus will do it

[Key-based SSH login with Nautilus' "Connect to Server"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102608/key-based-ssh-login-with-nautilus-connect-to-server)

You can also use gftp

[image: gftp]