# Ubuntu 14.04 Nautilus "connect to server..." window changed

Tags: nautilus, ssh, sftp

I'm having trouble because I want to connect to my EC2 server through my new installation of Ubuntu 14.04 and I just can't.

I already downloaded the .pem key and added my server to the ~/.ssh/config file like so:

```
Host myhost 
HostName myhostdns
User ubuntu
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey.pem
Compression yes
```

I also found that the window changed from this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCz3x.png]

To this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLdxC.jpg]

I now I could use another client but I'm configuring this machine as simple as I can.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### **Finally solved it!**

I don't know why but Nautilus 3.10 treats in an odd way the ~/.ssh/config file, or at least this is what I've experienced.

This is how my ~/.ssh/config file looks like:

```
Host aws_host
  HostName [host ip addres]
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/your_key.pem
```

**DO NOT use your DNS name on your "Host" OR "HostName" variables** or you may get an error saying *Unable to find the requested location. Please check the spelling or the network settings.* or an error saying *Don't have permission to access the requested location.*

The next step is to go to **File -> Connect to Server...** and in the **Server Address** bar write: **sftp://ubuntu@aws_host** and you should get your sftp drive mounted.

### [image]

I'm really surprised of how difficult it was to find this simple answer on the internet, everybody just goes around and sugests that you use Filezilla.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the IP or URL of the server, preceded by ssh like this:

ssh://(ip address) or ssh://URL

See the example:

[image]

As you see, you can use other prefix like smb (samba) sftp (FTP over SSH), dav for webdav or davs for webdav over SSL.

Comment: I've tried it but I get a message saying "Don't have permission to access the requested location".

Comment: The same happens if I use sftp:// instead of ssh://

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is if you reinstalled your client, maybe the keys are no longer recognized by the server. Can you connect trough terminal with ssh normally? Also, as a recommendation I switched from nautilus to nemo, which in the latest version has a much better interface than  nautilus.

Comment: I can connect through the terminal with the command:
ssh -i .ssh/mykey.pem ubuntu@myhost.com
I can also connect through gnome3 (Debian) and even on a Mac using Cyberduck

Comment: Also with Filezilla in the same machine